# PHPUnit Stubbing consecutive calls

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking

I have got a problem with a class, which returns unpredictable values and unit testing a method which calls that functions. So I'm going to change the return of a method.

I'm not able to mock that method because I cannot create the instance. Here is an example:

```
// Class called MyClass
public function doSomething(){
    $foo = new Foo();
    $bar = $foo->getSomethingUnpredictable();

    // Doing something with $bar and saves the result in $foobar.
    // The result is predictable if I know what $foo is.

    return $forbar;
}

// The test class
public function testDoSomething{
    $myClass = new MyClass();
    when("Foo::getSomethingUnpredictable()")->thenReturns("Foo");

    // Foo::testDoSomething is now predictable and I am able to create a assertEquals
    $this->assertEquals("fOO", $this->doSomething());
}
```

I might check what Foo::testDoSomething returns in the unit test and so calculate the result but than testDoSomething has only few distinction from doSomething. I also cannot check what happens with other values.
doSomething cannot have any parameters because varargs are used (so I cannot add an optimal parameter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why hardwired dependencies are bad, in its current state `doSomething` is not testable. You should refactor `MyClass` like that:

```
public function setFoo(Foo $foo)
{
    $this->foo = $foo;
}
public function getFoo()
{
    if ($this->foo === null) {
        $this->foo = new Foo();
    }
    return $this->foo;
}
public function doSomething(){
    $foo = $this->getFoo();
    $bar = $foo->getSomethingUnpredictable();

    // Doing something with $bar and saves the result in $foobar.
    // The result is predictable if I know what $foo is.

    return $forbar;
}
```

Then you will be able to inject your mocked `Foo` instance:

```
$myClass->setFoo($mock);
$actualResult = $myClass->doSomething();
```

As for how to stub the method, it depends on your test framework. Because this (`when("Foo::getSomethingUnpredictable()")->thenReturns("Foo");`) is not PHPUnit.